# Custom template deleter for std::unique_ptr not called

Tags: c++11

I have a bunch of third party object that needs to be released with a call to destroy. Since these objects needs to be allocated on the heap I wanted to create a std::unique_ptr to handle the memory managment. But my deleter never gets called.  What am I doing wrong?

```
template<typename T>
class ObjPtrDeleter
{
public:
    void operator()(T* obj)
    {
        if (obj)
            obj->destroy();
    }
};

int main(int args, char** argv)
{
   SomeFactory factory;
   std::unique_ptr<ISomeInterface1, ObjPtrDeleter<ISomeInterface1>> obj1(factory.create(1));
   std::unique_ptr<ISomeInterface2, ObjPtrDeleter<ISomeInterface2>> obj2(factory.create(2));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong is apparent. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The third party library had not define a virtual destructor for the abstract base class. That was why my custom deleter was never called.